Why the L3 Cache-ways values are different in ' /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index3/ways_of_associativity' and 'dmidecode'
I use two methods to get the value of ways of set in L3 Cache, but I the output are different:
# dmidecode -t cache
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L3 Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 3
    Installed Size: 64 MB
    Maximum Size: 64 MB
    Associativity: 16-way Set-associative

and
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cache/index3/ways_of_associativity
15

why one is 16-way while another is 15?
Besides, I'm searching for the MPAM technology.Here is an e.g:
> mount -t resctrl resctrl /sys/fs/resctrl -o mbMax,mbMin,caPrio
> cd /sys/fs/resctrl && cat schemata
     L3:0=0x7fff;1=0x7fff;2=0x7fff;3=0x7fff #default select cpbm as basic ctrl feature
     L3PRI:0=3;1=3;2=3;3=3
     MBMAX:0=100;1=100;2=100;3=100
     MBMIN:0=0;1=0;2=0;3=0

It seems they use the value 0x7FFF, which means 15 bits are enabled. So the real cache-ways value is 15 or 16? Why they are different in two different commands output?
I've searched a lot of documents , but I didn't find out the physical architecture of L3 Cache-ways, so I don't know which of the two values (15 and 16) is real.
